# Cloud storage/vault with valid/reliable biometric authentication to store emergency kit, private keys, etc for consumer market

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud, storage, openid-connect, recovery

I am searching for a cloud service that offers valid/reliable (ie, repeatable) biometric authentication to the consumer market. This service should function either as a direct access control mechanism for a data store or as an OpenID Identity Provider, enabling indirect access control to another cloud storage service.The purpose, is to store an emergency kit, consisting of private keys, recovery codes, etc, where acces to that kit cannot be lost, forgotten and/or otherwise fumbled.

In laymens, I want to be able to store a tiny payload of important stuff, where access is not dependant upon ana mfa device that I <strike>can</strike> will lose, a usb-type storage disk that I <strike>can</strike> will definitely lose and most importantly, a password that I will, most likely, not be able to remember in <strike>5 years</strike> 6 months. Biometric authentication, that is tightly coupled to a device, like a yubi key, phone, etc fits the mold of "things that I will lose".

If such a service exists, I would expect to have to pay for it, at a consumer-level rate, so anything specifically aimed at businesses, like okta, would not fit. Privacy concerns, emergency kit encryption and other security stuff is not my concern and am just curious is such a cloud service paradigm exists.

Cheers